# replacing file into WAR file which is generated by mvn package

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

i have a maven project and i want when using `clear package` maven command to replace config file from source code and replace it with exciting one in the WAR.
i tried but the replacing only happens in extracted folder not WAR file
this is my pom.xml

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <outputDirectory>target/Project-xyz/classes/resources</outputDirectory>  
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java/resources/customers</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Please elaborate exactly what you like to do and why need to do? Cause I don't understand your question..

Comment: let we assume i have file called A..css , this file in my resources. when generating WAR file i need to replace this file with another one called B.css how i can do this in pom.xml ?

Comment: Why is not `B.css` in the project instead of `A.css`?

Comment: because when creating the war file i need the war with a specific styles not my local style

Comment: So your real problem is: You want one CSS for local builds and one CSS for official builds?

Comment: yes i do ,but from pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

after so many trials it worked by using

> org.apache.maven.plugins

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-war</id>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/resources/customer1/css</directory>
                        <targetPath>resources/css</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```